# how to set mac command key for keybinding in emacs

Tags: emacs

I want to set my command key on my Mac to work like 'command-t' so I can use it with the helm plugin...I want to add this to my .emacs file. What is ???? for mac command key?

```
(global-set-key (kbd "????-t") 'helm-mini)
```

Answer (score 1):

Found it...after hunting for the complete list of currently set bindings via c-h b(ctrl h then b)....the answer is...s-t...so...

```
(global-set-key (kbd "s-t") 'helm-mini)
```

Now helm works like textmate's command-t.